# Should the peak displacement always match the peak amplitude of Fourier transform?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fast-fourier-transform

I am simulating the displacement as a function of time of an elastic body subject to a chirped sinusoidal force. The force chirps linearly from 0 Hz to 10 Hz over 10 seconds. The result of the simulation is displacement as a function of time, sampled at 1000 Hz. Data is available at [this google sheets link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k6-GaL8I7nLfru-Hs29qGySvzcSob8m2qbFRtAmZEQI/edit?usp=sharing).

The chirped sinusoidal force is given by
$$
F(t) = A \left( 1 - \cos\left(2 \pi \left( \frac{c}{2}t^2\right) \right)\right),
$$
where $c = 10\,\mathrm{Hz/s}$ and $A$ is an arbitrary amplitude constant.

The displacement as a function of time shown below (Image 1) has a peak amplitude at about 2.4 s, which corresponds to a frequency of **24 Hz**. However, when taking the fast Fourier transform (my code is given at the bottom), a clear peak emerges at **21.5 Hz** (Image 2).

**Is this likely the result of a mistake in my data analysis approach, or is there a mathematical reason why the maximum displacement might not line up with the peak in the spectrum?**

---

### Image 1: Displacement as a function of time

[image: Simulated displacement as a function of time. Max amplitude at 2.4 seconds]

### Image 2: Displacement as a function of frequency

[image: Simulated displacement as a function of frequency. Peak at 21.5 Hz]

### FFT Code

[Code Borrowed From Here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html)

```
dt = time(2)-time(1);           %Calculate the time step
Fs = 1/dt;                      %Calculate the sampling frequency
Y = fft(dispdata);              %Take Fast Fourier Transform
L = length(dispdata);           %Find length of the input data
P2 = abs(Y/L);                  %Compute the 2-sided spectrum
P1 = P2(1:L/2+1);               %compute the single-sided spectrum P1 based on P2 and the even-valued signal length L
P1(2:end-1) = 2*P1(2:end-1);
f = Fs*(0:(L/2))/L;             %Compute the frequency domain
```

Answer (score 1):

Just figured it out. The frequency according to the equation above is $f = \frac{c}{2} t^2$. This makes the chirp linear in *frequency*, but ***not linear in time***! You can't simply get the frequency of the peak displacement by multiplying the time by 10! I will trust the Fourier transform.